# Google Cloud Platform - Compute Engine Bitnami Mean stack startup script

Tags: google-compute-engine, mean-stack, startup, bitnami

I'm running a Bitnami MEAN instance and added a few lines to the startup script meta tag. I don't think it's running. I tailed the log files per the instructions here: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript  after adding some debug statements and I don't see any of my debug statements in the log.  Does the startup-script commands not run on a bitnami vm??? Maybe it's overwritten somewhere for another script.  I don't see it documented in the Bitnami docs.

I also ran the startup manually from a terminal

```
sudo google_metadata_script_runner --script-type startup
```

and it worked.  So maybe Bitnami overrides the default startup script???

Answer (score 0):

To check if the instance is bypassing startup scripts you can do the following:

1 Go to the [VM instances page](https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/instances?_ga=1.53606636.539578396.1475491682).

2 Click on the instance for which you want to add a startup script.

3 Click the Edit button at the top of the page.

4 Under Custom metadata, search for the following key:

If there are a `startup-script` key, then the instance is loading and executing startup scripts, and the problem is in how you are loaded the script.

Comment: There is a startup-script key, that's where I put my code.  The code isn't being executed from that key/value pair within the instance details on startup.  If i manually run the same line of code after the instance says it's up then it works.  So not sure if it's a timing issue (which I tried a few things to check to make sure the services are up before trying to start the app, etc).  I don't see any output in the logs.  Any other suggestions to try?